# Тень снизу и боков для UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, box-shadow

Каким образом можно добавить для кнопки тень и боковые бордеры с такими параметрами?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробую тень для кнопки сделать так:

```
testButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2).cgColor
testButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
testButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
testButton.layer.shadowRadius = 0
testButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0
testButton.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. тень добавляется к тайтлу кнопки, но не к самой кнопке
2. как добавить к тени blur, который есть в макете?
3. каким образом добавить пару боковых бордеров снаружи кнопки?

Comment: В чем именно заключается проблема с добавлением тени?

Comment: @VAndrJ обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, по порядку, лучше цвет задавать без прозрачности, а прозрачность указывать для тени:

```
testButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
testButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
```

1: Тень считается по альфа-каналу, соответственно, так как кнопка прозрачная, то добавляется она только к надписи. Достаточно прописать:

```
testButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

2:3: Чтобы добавить blur необходимо указать shadowRadius:

```
testButton.layer.shadowRadius = 2
```

cornerRadius по умолчанию 0 и masksToBounds false, их можно не указывать.

В итоге для добавления тени кнопке все что необходимо прописать:

```
testButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
testButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
testButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
testButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
testButton.layer.shadowRadius = 2
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также учитывайте, что количество пикселей == shadowRadius*scale + на плавный переход (чем больше радиус, тем больше пикселей на переход). Также можно ее добавить как отдельный layer, а его растеризировать для снижения нагрузки.

Comment: большое спасибо за развернутый ответ ) Можно еще попросить рассказать (или дать ссылку) на вот это: "Также можно ее добавить как отдельный layer, а его растеризировать для снижения нагрузки."?

Comment: @xhr небольшая статейка где кратко описывается: http://angelolloqui.com/blog/30-iOS-Performance-tips-I-Drawing-shadows . Основная проблема - отрисовка тени довольно ресурсоемкая. Поэтому просто указание пути для layer снижает нагрузку. В общем, все нужно смотреть по ситуации. Если это одна кнопочка с тенью, сцена статическа, то можно и не беспокоиться.